# docker-compose não utiliza env adquiridas pelo eval

Tags: docker

Fala pessoal,
Estou com uma issue bem estranha no meu ambiente. Estou começando com docker ainda.

O que eu quero é rodar um docker-compose em um swarm-master que foi criado no virtual box local(via docker-machine).  Já rodei o comando eval$(docker-machine env --swarm node_name), mas toda vez que uso o docker ou docker-compose CLI, ele tenta executar na minha máquina e não na VM.

Isso funcionou bem quando utilizei uma maquina virtual como meu computador, e o swarm criado no digitalocean. Mas pra evitar custos mudei a abordagem para seguir com os estudos.

Utilizo Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom pessoal, consegui resolver. Foi só mudar as permissões do docker-machine que tudo passou a funcionar normalmente. 
Só cuidado que mudar as permissões, por algum motivo, fez as máquinas que estavam montadas desconfigurarem.

abração.